# MySQL / PHP - Count occurrence of word in a column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table of locations that gets populated with different countries.
I want to count the occurrence of each country and insert it into a new table called 'Locations'.

### Location Table

```
ID | Location            | Count|
1  | United Kingdom      | 5    |
2  | United States       | 2    |
3  | Country Unavailable | 3    |
```

The code below will insert into the database all countries that are unavailable.

What's the best logic to count the occurrence of the unknown string?

```
<?
    $country = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT Location, COUNT(location) 
    FROM TWEETS WHERE location LIKE 'country unavailable'");
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($country))
{
    $country_count=$row[0];
    mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT INTO Location(location, count) VALUES
   ('country unavailable', '$country_count')"); 
}
?>
```

Sorry the above statement works for me I didn't make this clear.
So this will count country unavailable and insert it into the database. 
My issue is that I want to insert a location with a value but I won't know what the location is so I can't use 'like'.

What is the work around? This is what I want to work :

```
<?
 $country = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT Location, COUNT(location) FROM TWEETS
 WHERE location LIKE '?????????????'");
 while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($country))
 {
 $country_string=$row[0];
 $country_count=$row[0];
 mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT INTO Location(location, count) VALUES
 ('$country_string', '$country_count')");
}
```

?>

So if my database returns 10 locations, one of them may just be Australia. It has to be able to take in that string and count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you wanna use count.. you have to group by

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Location (location, count) 
               SELECT Location, COUNT(location) 
                 FROM TWEETS 
                WHERE location LIKE 'Country Unavailable' 
             GROUP BY Location";
```

-> Insert a new datarow 'Country Unavailable', 2(count)

do you really want to insert a new datarow ? or maybe update ?

```
$query =  "UPDATE Location
             SET count = (
               SELECT COUNT(location) 
                 FROM TWEETS 
                WHERE location LIKE 'Country Unavailable' 
             GROUP BY Location)
           WHERE Location = 'Country Unavailable'";
```

Edit:

I'm not sure whether I get your question right, but shouldn't the following work?

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Location (location, count)
                   SELECT t.Location, Count(*) FROM TWEETS t
                LEFT JOIN Location l 
                       ON t.location = l.Location
                    WHERE l.Location is null
                 GROUP BY t.Location"
```

Comment: Hi apologies I poorly phrased this question - the above code works for me. The second code block doesn't, I want to take a location that I won't know from the results table.

Comment: ah ok :). i had extend my answer. it will add all countries from Tweets where are NOT int your Location table

Comment: Okay, I think this is nearly it. My problem is that I truncate the location table each time. So it only has id, location, count. So when I use this query now i stills doesn't go into the database.

Comment: #1052 - Column 'Location' in field list is ambiguous is the error I'm getting

Comment: ups.. i forgot the 't.' in 'SELECT t.Location, Count(*) FROM TWEETS t'.. but when you turncate the Location table, it will insert ALL Locations from TWEETS.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in just one query, like:

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO Location (location, count) 
 SELECT Location, COUNT(location) FROM TWEETS WHERE location LIKE 'Country Unavailable'";

 mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
```

Comment: Thanks this actually helped clean up my other code. I have put more clarity on my issue.